# Best approach to divide column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have divided my grid system following way.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
           <div class="slider"></div>
           <!--divided column into 6/6-->
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <img src="img/2.jpg" style="width: 150px;height: 150px;" class="img-thumbnail" />
               <img src="img/2.jpg" style="width: 150px;height: 150px;" class="img-thumbnail"/>
               <img src="img/2.jpg" style="width: 150px;height: 150px;" class="img-thumbnail"/>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <p>some content with image</p>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
           some content plus image
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

My problem is I can't set 3 images in that div because of less width. Can any one tell how I can make it work. If I am doing any think wrong in my grid system please guide me.

Thank you

Comment: Add class "com-md-4" into **img** tag. this might solve your issue

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="slider"></div>
            <!--divided column into 6/6-->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/2.jpg" style="width: 150px;height: 150px;" class="img-thumbnail" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/2.jpg" style="width: 150px;height: 150px;" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/2.jpg" style="width: 150px;height: 150px;" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                </div>                 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>some content with image</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            some content plus image
        </div>
</div>
```

Hope This will work..

Answer (score 1):

You can use with to adding a custom class

```css
.thumb_img .img-thumbnail{
    width:32%;
    padding:4px;
    margin-right:1%;
    float:left;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <!--divided column into 6/6-->
        <div class="col-md-6 thumb_img">
          <div class="row">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" />
            <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" />
            <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>some content with image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @maddy.thank you. i will try.but i think images will display small.is there better way to divide my grid system.

Comment: Yes image will be small, because it depend on your gird width. If it will possible, then you should show Image vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Not a 100% sure about your question but..

1) you can only nest `col-`'s in `row`'s. i.e:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
```

2) each time you've divided a row in multiple columns, then inside the nested row you have 12 columns available again. i.e:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can create 3 columns inside a row:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

I.e. 4 * 3 = 12 columns.

Comment: @Luke.yes you are right.but if add row inside my column then once again i get less space.so i didnt added